# Using Flexbox to Responsively Wrap 3 Boxes and their Content

Tags: css, flexbox

I've created a jsfiddle to illustrate what I'm trying to do.  When you resize the window smaller, the boxes overlap.  Another  problem that I'm having is getting the "read more" text to go the bottom right of each box.

https://jsfiddle.net/natetg/dhaqzy29/1/

```
<header>header</header>
<div id='main'>
<leftCol>left
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="right">read more</div>
    </div>
</leftCol>
<middleCol>middle
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="right">read more</div>
    </div>
</middleCol>
<rightCol>right
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="right">read more</div>
    </div>
</rightCol>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle that shows how to align to the bottom right, but it doesn't work in my example.  http://jsfiddle.net/blake770/2br5x/

Comment: So what do you need help with?

Comment: The read more text needs to be in the bottom right of each box.  And, when you view the page on a small screen, the boxes can't overlap and look bad like they do now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#box-container
{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
.box
{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex:1;
    min-width:250px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.box-title
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.box-text
{
    flex:1;   
}
.box-read-more
{
    align-self:flex-end;
}


<div id="box-container">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-title">
        Box #1 title
    </div>
    <div class="box-text">
        Text content for the box goes here.
    </div>
    <div class="box-read-more">
        Read more...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-title">
        Box #2 title
    </div>
    <div class="box-text">
        Text content for the box goes here.
    </div>
    <div class="box-read-more">
        Read more...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-title">
        Box #3 title
    </div>
    <div class="box-text">
        Text content for the box goes here.
    </div>
    <div class="box-read-more">
        Read more...
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```